# restart loop after winning the game

Tags: python

```
number = int(input("please choose your number: "))

while number != number_to_guess:
    if number > number_to_guess:
        number = int(input("Your guess is wrong it was bigger then the generated number, try again: "))
        continue
    if number < number_to_guess :
        number = int(input("Your guess was wrong it was smaller then the generated number, try again: "))

if number == number_to_guess:
    print("Congrats you won")
    restart = input("Do you want to play again? if yes type y, if not you can close the window \n")

while restart not in ["y"]:
    restart = input("please type y or close the window \n")
```

i want it as the title suggest to restart after the user types y, and i want it to always start with number input"choose your..." but i have no idea of how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can write the code in a function, and then, if you want to restart, call that function again

```
def game():
    number = int(input("please choose your number: "))
    number_to_guess = 5

    while number != number_to_guess:
        if number > number_to_guess:
            number = int(input("Your guess is wrong it was bigger then the generated number, try again: "))
            continue
        if number < number_to_guess :
            number = int(input("Your guess was wrong it was smaller then the generated number, try again: "))

    if number == number_to_guess:
        print("Congrats you won")
        restart = input("Do you want to play again? if yes type y, if not you can close the window \n")
        if restart == "y":          #restart the game
            game()

    while restart not in ["y"]:
        restart = input("please type y or close the window \n")

# main code
game()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use functions or a while loop for this.

with functions,

```py
def game():
   #implement game here
   number = input()
   #other stuff

while True:
   game()
   restart = input()
   if restart != 'y':
      break # exit game
```

Note: this is pretty basic logic, refer to the tutorials [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_functions.htm) for more information on functions and loops.